# Сохранить скачанный файл

Tags: swift

Народ! Кто в теме подскажите как сохранить скачанный файл в правильную папку приложения? Есть код скачивания удаленного *.xml -файла .. как его сохранить? Из какой переменной вытаскивать после скачивания и построить путь сохранения для хранеия и перезаписи при необходимости

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://........./file.xml")!
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
if error != nil {
NSLog("%@", "Error: \(error)");
return
}

NSLog("Loaded %i bytes", data!.length)
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

решил собственный вопрос
переменная filename обычная строка

```
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

        let paramString = "data=Hello"
        request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (
            let location, let response, let error) in

            guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
try! urlContents.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



            guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

        }

        task.resume()
```